# Working with multiple repository in BitBucket

Tags: git, bitbucket

On my laptop, I have my bitbucket key configured. On BitBucket, I am part of two teams. One team is say **TeamA** and the other one is **TeamB**.

I recently worked on one of the project for **TeamX** say **TeamX.Project1**. I did all commits, pushed it etc. One thing to note that my `origin` is configured to this team.

Now here are steps that i did for **TeamB**

- Create a new directory somewhere else in the system
- executed `git init`
- Created new `README.MD` file by `echo "First Time" > README.MD`
- added new team repo to this directory by `git remote add team2_origin git@bitbucket.org:myusername/team2_project1.git`
- and then did `git push -u personal_origin --all`

What I was expecting that I will have only `README.MD` file in this project however, to my surprise, **TeamB.prject_1** had all the history of **TeamA.Project1**. Also, it showed me that my `README.MD` (which i newly created) has been changed since it was tracking **TeamA**.README.MD as previous version.

I didn't want that. I want to keep both teams and their project totally isolated.

How to do so

**EDIT**

Path to **TeamA.Project1**: `/Users/myname/Documents/dev/repos/project_1`

Path to **TeamB.Project1**: `/Users/myname/Documents/dev/teamb/project_1`

Comment: I have tens of projects on GitHub and BitBucket (and redmine and whatever), but it has never happened to me. Show `~/.gitconfig`, and `.git/config` in each repository. Also, what are the paths to both the working directories? Are you sure they aren't included one in another (maybe via a symlink)?

Comment: You know what, I guess, I might have just figured what did i do. when i executed `push` command, I was in `teamA.project_1` directory instead of `teamB.project_1` directory :) ... One question, is there a command to remove newly added `personal_origin` from `teamA.project_1` reference ?

Comment: You can use `git remote remove` to remove a remote.